# Docker: how to unset the environment variable in container which is provided by `docker run -e FOO=bar` command?

Tags: docker

For example, I have a dockerfile which has a `ENTRYPOINT` command:

```
From alpine:latest
WORKDIR /app/
RUN apk add --no-cache bash && echo 'echo foo:$FOO' > echo.sh && cat echo.sh && chmod a+x echo.sh 

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "_FOO=$FOO ./echo.sh && unset FOO && sleep 30"]
```

Then I run this docker and pass env `FOO` with value `bar`:

```
$ docker run --rm -e FOO=bar --name=demo docker-image-demo
```

How to unset the **environment variable FOO in container** which is provided by `docker run -e FOO=bar` command ?

```
$ docker exec -it demo bash
$ bash-5.0$ echo $FOO
bar
```

I try to use `exec` to replace container process with `bash`, but I get some error:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["exec", "sh", "-c", "_FOO=$FOO ./echo.sh && unset FOO && sleep 30"]
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: "exec": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: Never needed this myself. What's your purpose of hiding it? If someone is already inside of the container, they must have known that value (presumably only a secret is worth hiding;).

Comment: @mirekphd this FOO stores http-server's secret. Such as `docker run -e PASSWORD` and `./http-server && unset PASSWORD && sleep 300000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [docker secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) for this purpose. Injecting secrets to the container via env variables is perfectly acceptable - even security-hardened Openshift permits it in their Templates.

If the adversary is already inside of the server container, then they must have hacked the very password you are trying to hide here. Or they gained access to your machine and can execute docker commands (`docker` group password is usually at the same level as `sudo`, so it means you have been hacked down to root level) or have your CLI password in case of Openshift, so they can connect to remote shells in all other containers in your namespace and do whatever they please. So hiding env vars seems now a bit too late.

Answer (score 0):

You do it with the `unset` shell built-in, exactly as you're doing it.

However: `docker exec` shells do not run as children of your entrypoint, so any changes the entrypoint makes to the environment won't be visible to those shells.  This usually isn't a practical problem, since you should usually reserve `docker exec` for occasional debugging tasks.

One way to see this is to edit your Dockerfile to run the `echo.sh` script again after the `unset` command.

---

You can also restructure this to use an entrypoint wrapper script, and honor the Docker `CMD`.  For example, we could take the long command in your current `ENTRYPOINT` line and rewrite it into a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Do any first-time setup that's required
echo "FOO was '$FOO'"
unset FOO
echo "FOO is now '$FOO'"

# Then run the main container command, replacing this script
exec "$@"
```

You can then invoke this in the Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM alpine:latest
# RUN apk add --no-cache bash
WORKDIR /app
COPY echo.sh entrypoint.sh .  # will preserve executable bit

# Must use JSON-array syntax; must not use `sh -c` wrapper
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
# Can be anything
CMD sleep 30
```

Now if you build this image, you can `docker run` it with an alternate command.  For example, if you just want to see the environment the main container process will run with, you can

```
docker run --rm docker-image-demo env
```

Comment: I can still find FOO's value if I run `docker exec -it <contanier>`.

Answer (score 0):

[Google's distroless images](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) by default do not have any shell (even `sh`), so they are ideal for hiding environment variables and protecting scripted apps code (if you are lucky to use the supported languages such as Go, Java, or Rust, sadly not python yet).

---

*More info*

As for debugging during development time, these images have also special dev versions with `busybox` installed (and thus `sh`) - it's enough to switch to the `debug` tag:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:debug
/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
```

... versus my vain hacking attempts of the shell-less production version of the same container:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'docker run --help'.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest cat /etc/shells
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "cat": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest echo $SHELL
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "echo": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest echo $PATH
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "echo": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest cat $PATH
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "cat": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest cat $SHELL
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "cat": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest sh
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest bash
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest busybox
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "busybox": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest id
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "id": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled 

$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:latest env
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "env": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```